# Rails 3 - Disable cache for filename in file_column plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uuid

This is my code to obtain an UUID:

```
  def manage_id
    self.id = UUIDTools::UUID.random_create().to_s.upcase if self.id.blank?
  end
```

This works perfectly for the primary key of my object.

My problem is I want to name an uploaded file with an UUID... and I obtain the same UUID for different uploads. For example I will have an UUID and 2 minutes later with another object I will have the same UUID !

This is the class code to name my image:

```
:filename => "#{UUIDTools::UUID.random_create().to_s.upcase}.jpg" }
```

I don't understand what can be the problem when generating the UUID...

I have not the problem in development !!!

EDIT 1: the problem is not with UUID itself, it's the same with a timestamp... (and only in production)

EDIT 2: I found the problem. The setting:

config.cache_classes = true

is the problem in production mode. It is certainly keeping the UUID somewhere in memory.

I think I can't switch to false in production mode (for performance), so what is the best way to deactivate the cache for this plugin name feature ?

EDIT 3: I add the full code of my model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

 file_column :image, {:magick => { :versions => { "tiny" => "70x70", "small" => "160x240", "high" => "640x960" }}, :store_dir => "public/upload/wine/image", :web_root => "upload/", :filename => "#{UUIDTools::UUID.timestamp_create().to_s.upcase}.jpg" }

end
```

So, as I said the UUID generated is cached in production. I don't know how to force this model or maybe the plugin file_column to not be cached ?

Comment: add full examples of your code plz

Comment: I added the full code. Thanks.

Comment: honestly I can't find declaration about :filename option in this plugin. Do you use this one https://github.com/tekin/file_column?

Comment: Sorry, I added the option filename here: http://railspro.blogspot.fr/2010/12/filename-rename-in-file-column_964.html?showComment=1335383861327

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that it doesn't work for you because you always use pre-initialized option.
But you can try to change something to improve it. For example you can use lambda expression for calcaulationg filename ... Try something like next

```
file_column :image, {:magick => 
                            { :versions => 
                                { "tiny" => "70x70", "small" => "160x240", "high" => "640x960" }
                             },
                             :store_dir => "public/upload/wine/image", 
                             :web_root => "upload/", 
                             :filename => lambda { "#{UUIDTools::UUID.timestamp_create().to_s.upcase}.jpg"} }
```

and change this

> Assign filename to temp image path. Update code @class TempUploadedFile store_upload method line number 219

```
@filename = options[:filename] || FileColumn::sanitize_filename(file.original_filename)
```

to

```
options_file_name = options[:filename].respond_to?(:call) ? options[:filename].call : options[:filename]


   @filename = options_file_name || FileColumn::sanitize_filename(file.original_filename)
```

Comment: It works perfectly ! Great job ! It's a drama because I tried Paperclip last hours and now I have the 2 options !

Comment: I think paper_clip is more up-to-date and powerful gem than this plugin

Comment: Exact. I hacked file_column several years. Time to change. I just hope Paperclip is not consuming too much memory.